# Apply column search to current jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, datatables

I have a current jQuery DataTable in place that is functioning properly:

```
 var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
   "ajax": 'api/tableSearch.php',
   "iDisplayLength": 25,
   "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
   "scrollY": 600,
   "scrollX": true,
   "bDestroy": true,
   "columnDefs": [{
     "targets": 0,
     "render": function (data, type, full, meta){
       return '<a class="editLink" href="#">Edit</a><a class="deleteLink" href="#">Del</a>':
     }
   }]
 });
```

As stated, the above code works accordingly...the search filter works, the sorting works, everything works.

What I would like to do is add a column search to this datatable, as shown here:
     https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

I attempted to add the code from the link above to my current code, as follows:

```
 var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
   "ajax": 'api/tableSearch.php',
   "iDisplayLength": 25,
   "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
   "scrollY": 600,
   "scrollX": true,
   "bDestroy": true,
   "columnDefs": [{
     "targets": 0,
     "render": function (data, type, full, meta){
       return '<a class="editLink" href="#">Edit</a><a class="deleteLink" href="#">Del</a>':
     }
   }],  // begin here
   initComplete: function(){
     this.api().columns().every(function(){
       var column = this;
       var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
       .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
       .on( 'change', function () {
         var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
           );
         column
           .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
           .draw();
         } );
         column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
           select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
         } );
        } );
      }
    } );        
 });
```

I have not received any errors, and the DataTable still loads, but the column search is not there.

I am using jQuery-2.1.3.min, so it should be up to date.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong and what I can do to correct this issue?

Comment: do you have a ```<tfoot>``` in your table markup? It may be required for the following to work: ```var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
       .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )```

Comment: That's what it was...I needed to add a footer to the table.  But now, my columns are misaligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<tfoot>` to your table. The expression referencing `column.footer()` expects it to exist.